# Resampling of a series of numerical values using Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, signal-processing, interpolation

Using dart/flutter, how do you perform linear interpolation to upsample/downsample on a series of numerical values data of type `List<List<double>>` to another frequency if you are given the original frequency value?

For example,

- if the frequency of data is 20 Hz, we want to convert it to 10 Hz using linear interpolation.
- if the frequency of data is 20 Hz, we also want to be able to convert it to 30 Hz using linear interpolation.

In Python, you have `resampy` so you can simply do

```
resampy.resample(np.asarray(data), 20, 10)
```